# Number of days since joined shown for an account on the accounts list is 1 or 2 days less than the correct number

Tags: feature-request, bug, user-accounts, information-display, dates

Note: Since I posted this question, I'm quite certain I figured out what is going on, and now have a feature request, with this described in the Update section further down. However, for anybody interested, I'm leaving the original details and my initial thoughts on the issue.

About 10 days ago, I joined the [Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) site. The top-right part of my [profile page](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/12978/john-omielan?tab=profile) shows

[image: Math Educators account profile page]

Hovering my mouse over the "Member for 10 days" line results in a tool-tip with "2019-10-31 23:08:41Z", which I recall is the correct date & time of when I joined.

However, my [accounts list](https://stackexchange.com/users/14503071/john-omielan?tab=accounts) shows

[image: Math Educators account list]

I first noticed this discrepancy about 5 or 6 days ago, with it consistently showing a difference of 2 days since then. Unfortunately, I don't recall what it showed during the first few days after I joined. On the chance the system might have fixed this itself, I waited until now to report the problem.

As far as I know, the number of days since a user joined an account does not depend on them needing to first doing anything in particular. There are several other accounts which I joined where I've only viewed questions, answers and up voted, with all of these accounts always showing, as I recall, the correct # of days in the account list. Note that with Math Educators, my [votes activity list](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users/12978/john-omielan?tab=votes) shows I gave 6 up votes on Oct. 31, and quite a few more on Nov. 1.

My first comments, response, and answer occurred on Nov. 2, i.e., 8 days ago. Is this possibly the cause of the discrepancy? If so, I don't believe this should have happened (e.g., this is not documented anywhere that I know of). For example, for [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/users/129887/john-omielan?tab=activity), my first activity other than viewing questions/answers or up voting was a comment on Jan. 27, and my first answer was on June 29. Nonetheless, my [accounts list](https://stackexchange.com/users/14503071/john-omielan?tab=accounts) correctly states that I joined "1 year, 1 month ago".

Has anybody else noticed a discrepancy like this themselves, have any idea of what may be causing it, and what (if anything) I can do to correct it?

**Update**:

As the [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337815/number-of-days-since-joined-shown-for-an-account-on-the-accounts-list-is-2-days#comment1124009_337815) indicates, there's a period of time when the number of days difference is just 1. I saw it was 2 days difference at about 23:06Z, but just 1 day difference at 23:09Z. Since I joined at 23:08:41Z, I'm quite certain what the system is doing is determining the time difference, most likely in seconds, and calculating the number of days (e.g., by dividing by 86400 if working with seconds) by always rounding down the result to the next lowest integer (i.e., discard any fractional part). Thus, if this result is 0, the notice will say joined today, and otherwise it'll say that the person joined this number of days ago. This exactly matches what I see. However, I request this handling be changed so the result matches what is shown in the profile page, as it doesn't make sense to me to have 2 different ways to calculate the number of days people have been members of a site. This discrepancy just causes unnecessary confusion, as it did with me, and also likely will with other people.

Comment: For me, it's (now) showing 9 days on the network account list, and 10 days on the site itself. Since there's no tooltip on the network account list, we can't be sure, unless they are using different calculations or timezones (e.g. local vs UTC) for unknown reasons.